# What causes the slice is not a function error in this Vue 3 and TypeScript app?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have been working on an SPA with **Vue 3**, **TypeScript** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**.

In `src\components\MovieDetails.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
      <div class="poster-container text-center text-sm-start my-3">
        <img v-if="movie"
          :src="genericPoster"
          :alt="movie?.title"
          class="img-fluid shadow-sm"
        />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
      <h1 class="movie-title mt-4">{{ movie?.original_title }}</h1>

      <p v-if="movie?.genres.length">
        <strong class="pe-1">Genres:</strong>
        <span
          class="badge bg-secondary"
          v-for="genre in movie?.genres"
          :key="genre.id"
          >{{ genre.name }}</span
        >
      </p>

      <p v-if="movie?.vote_average" class="user-score">
        <strong>User Score:</strong>
        <span class="score" :class="movieQuality">{{
          Number(movie?.vote_average).toFixed(2)
        }}</span>
      </p>

      <div v-if="movie?.overview">
        <h2 class="section-title">Overview</h2>
        <p>{{ movie.overview }}</p>
      </div>

      <div v-if="movieTrailers.length" class="mb-3">
        <h2 class="section-title">Trailers</h2>
        <TrailerCarousel :movieTrailers="movieTrailers" />
      </div>

      <div v-if="movieCast.length" class="cast-container">
        <h2 class="section-title">Cast</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <div
            v-for="actor in movieCast.slice(0, 12)"
            :key="actor['id']"
            class="col-sm-3"
          >
            <ActorCard :actor="actor" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import env from "../env";
import { Movie } from "@/models/Movie";
import { Trailer } from "@/models/Trailer";
import { MovieCast } from "@/models/MovieCast";
import TrailerCarousel from "./TrailerCarousel.vue";
import ActorCard from "./ActorCard.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MovieDetails",

  components: {
    TrailerCarousel,
    ActorCard,
  },

  data: () => ({
    route: useRoute(),
    genericPosterBig: require('../assets/generic-poster.png'),
    movie: null as Movie | null,
    movieQuality: String as unknown | 'bad',
    movieCast: Array as unknown | MovieCast[]
    movieTrailers: Array as unknown | Trailer[]
  }),

  mounted() {
    this.getMovieDetails();
    this.getMovieTrailers();
    this.getMovieCast();
  },

  methods: {
    getMovieDetails() {
      this.$axios
        .get(
          `${env.api_url}/movie/${this.route.params.id}?api_key=${env.api_key}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          this.movie = response.data;
          // Once you get the movie, set its quality
          this.setMovieQuality();
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },

    setMovieQuality() {
      if (Number(this.movie?.vote_average) >= 7) {
         this.movieQuality = 'good';
      } else if(Number(this.movie?.vote_average) < 7 && Number(this.movie?.vote_average) > 5.5) {
         this.movieQuality =  'average';
      } else {
         this.movieQuality =  'bad';
      }
    },

    getMovieTrailers() {
      this.$axios
        .get(
          `${env.api_url}/movie/${this.route.params.id}/videos?api_key=${env.api_key}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          this.movieTrailers = response.data.results;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },

    getMovieCast() {
      this.$axios
        .get(
          `${env.api_url}/movie/${this.route.params.id}/credits?api_key=${env.api_key}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          this.movieCast = response.data.cast;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },
  },

  computed: {
    genericPoster() {
      return !this.movie?.poster_path
        ? this.genericPosterBig
        : `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.movie?.poster_path}`
    },
  },

  watch: {
    "$route.params.id"() {
      this.getMovieDetails();
      this.getMovieTrailers();
      this.getMovieCast();
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

In `src\models\MovieCast.ts`:

```
export interface MovieCast {
    adult?: boolean;
    character?: string;
    name?: string;
    profile_path?: string;
}
```

In stead of these 2 lines in the components

```
movieCast: Array as unknown | MovieCast[]
movieTrailers: Array as unknown | Trailer[]
```

I *used to have*:

```
movieTrailers: [],
movieCast: [],
```

I have made the change so that I would have a more **strictly/strongly typed** app.

#### The problem

Since the change, the console shows the error:

> TypeError: _ctx.movieCast.slice is not a function

```
<div
    v-for="actor in movieCast.slice(0, 12)"
    :key="actor['id']"
    class="col-sm-3"
  >
    <ActorCard :actor="actor" />
</div>
```

There is a **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-typescript-vue-cli-starter-7y9c7v)** too, with the working app.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: This occurs when `movieCast` has no value (e.g. `undefined` or `null`, or is not of the type you are expecting), try initialising the variable as an empty array `[]`. Additionally, you should not need to use the `unknown` type assertion (`movieCast: Array as unknown | MovieCast[]`), `movieCast: MovieCast[]` should be sufficient

Comment: `movieCast: Array` results in movieCast being a function, `as` cheats TS type system and prevents the mistakes from being caught at compilation time. Same for other data. I'd suggest to pay more attention to the syntax, what's JS runtime code and what are TS types.

Comment: Estus Flask has the right of it.  `data` is meant to declare initial values.  The way you've done it is just made everything constructor functions.  You _can_ include types, but the syntax is better explained by these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810218/set-data-type-in-vue-data-object-with-typescript)

Comment: @Harrison I use to have it as an empty array: `movieCast: []`, but in this case, what is the utility of importing a model, like `import { MovieCast } from "@/models/MovieCast"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are assigning a non-array, you will also get an error.  Try logging the type, and see what is actually returned.

```
console.log('movieCast', response.data.cast)
this.movieCast = response.data.cast;
```

Use a `conditional operator` to prevent an error while your async value is `undefined` and calculating.  You could also wrap the `v-for` in a `v-if` and check for undefined.

```
v-for="actor in movieCast?.slice(0, 12)"
```

Comment: I did that, it throws errors.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir Then you are not assigning an array to `movieCast`

Comment: I updated solution with a way to test your response type.

Comment: I need to use the `MovieCast` model without that throwing an error.